# UICollectionview fit to one line dynamically

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have words that come from the server, and dynamically I set up collection view, each cell shows one letter.

but if the word is too long then everything shrink.

[image]
[image]

I want each letter to fit into the collection view, the word should fit in one line only, so I used:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let numberOfSets = CGFloat(self.letters!.count)
    let width = (collectionView.frame.size.width - (numberOfSets * view.frame.size.width / 15))/numberOfSets
    let height = collectionView.frame.size.height / 2
    return CGSize(width : width, height : height)
}
```

Comment: You have to keep the collectionViewCell's width constant if you don't want them to shrink.

Comment: @SanketBhavsar I want them to shrink but with proportions.. how it can be constant? they will not fit into one line

Comment: is it okay if the text shrinks?

Comment: @SanketBhavsar sure

Comment: Tell me how you have designed the cell? I mean, the UIElements inside the cell.

Comment: @SanketBhavsar  only label that fit the cell, the cell size is 50*50, min spacing 5 for both cells and lines

Answer (score 0):

Select the `UILabel` and goto Attribute Inspector

[image: Attribute Inspector Snap]

Then select *Minimum Font Size* or *Minimum Font Scale* from Autoshrink option and finally set your desired **minimum** value.

Hope this works.

Comment: and you have set Minimum font size to?

Comment: I think you have set only horizontally and vertically center constraint to your label, right?

Comment: Please remove those constraints and add Leading, Trailing, Top, Bottom to the label from cell with constant=0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144649/discussion-between-sanket-bhavsar-and-knic1ned).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is keeping the cells left aligned, and with fixed cell width and padding between cells. Not a dynamic padding when there is few letters. You don't want "a b c" become "a........b........c". The solution is set a max padding between cells, unfortunately, there is no such setting with default collection view layout. You need to define one:

```
class MaxSpacingCollectionViewFlowLayout : UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        guard let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect) else {
            return nil
        }

        if attributes.count <= 0 { return attributes }

        let firstCellOriginX = attributes[0].frame.origin.x

        for i in 1..<attributes.count {
            let currentLayoutAttributes = attributes[i];
            if currentLayoutAttributes.frame.origin.x == firstCellOriginX {
                continue //first cell of a new row
            }

            let prevLayoutAttributes = attributes[i - 1]
            let prevOriginMaxX = prevLayoutAttributes.frame.maxX
            if currentLayoutAttributes.frame.origin.x - prevOriginMaxX > 8 { // 8 here is the max padding
                var frame = currentLayoutAttributes.frame
                frame.origin.x = prevOriginMaxX + 8
                currentLayoutAttributes.frame = frame
            }
        }

        return attributes
    }
}
```

Then replace the default layout:

```
  let collectionView = UICollectionView()
  //......
  collectionView.collectionViewLayout = MaxSpacingCollectionViewFlowLayout()
```

Finally, the delegate method `sizeForItemAt` could simplely return a fixed width:

```
  return CGSize(width : 35, height : 35)
```

Comment: Thanks!  But the lines splits when the text is too long: http://i.imgur.com/03P4ACd.png

Comment: Why not give collectionView more width? It's limited?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

let size: CGSize = self.letters[indexPath.row].size(attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18.0)])//18.0 replace it with your label font size.

let height = collectionView.frame.size.height / 2

return CGSize(width: size.width+2 , height: height)

}
```

Comment: what do you mean by `.letters[indexPath.row].size` ? to get the label font size?

Comment: `let size: CGSize = self.letters[indexPath.row].size(attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: YOUR_Label_Font_Size)])` would return the exact size your content required.

Comment: I have tested the above code and it is working for me atleast.